# Disable `noImplicitAny` TS rule for a single line

Tags: typescript, tslint, disable

I have enabled `"noImplicitAny": true` in `tsconfig.json` and I'm getting `TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{}'` error in my code space.

I want to disable this rule for a single line and I tried with below code, but it didn't work.

```
const mockElement = () => ({
  mount: jest.fn(),
  destroy: jest.fn(),
  on: jest.fn(),
  update: jest.fn(),
});

const mockElements = () => {
  const elements = {};
  return {
    create: jest.fn((type) => {
      // getting error from the bellow line
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-implicit-any
      elements[type] = mockElement();
      // getting error from the bellow line
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-implicit-any
      return elements[type];
    }),
    getElement: jest.fn((type) => {
      // getting error from the bellow line
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-implicit-any
      return elements[type] || null;
    }),
  };
};
```

Any suggestions for disabling the rule ONLY for a single line? (setting `"noImplicitAny": false` in tsconfig.json would work but not acceptable as it disables the rule at all)

Comment: This is a compiler rule, not a linter rule. What you're supposed to do is write correct code to bypass it.

Comment: You can [suppress a compiler error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) with `// @ts-ignore` on the previous line. That is very rarely a good idea, and it will suppress all errors on that line, not necessarily just the one you want to suppress - but without seeing a [mcve], nobody can suggest a proper solution.

Comment: @kaya3 updated the question with the code. Yes, `// @ts-ignore` works. But expected any other solution if possible.

Comment: OK. Basically you need to use a type annotation on `elements` - something like `{[k: string]: ReturnType<typeof mockElement>}` should work.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. If you put this as an answer, I can accept the answer.

Comment: `This is a compiler rule, not a linter rule. What you're supposed to do is write correct code to bypass it.` @VLAZ this comment is not helpful.

Comment: ts-ignore worked, thanks, should be accepted answer.   when writing tests for deliberately adversarial objects in a crypto lib, sometimes this is the best solution!

Answer (score -2):

it's an ESLint thing, not a typescript compiler thing. try this in your source

`// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any`

tho, this is for EXplicit any, but I think you can workaround by just defining it explicitly on the one line you need?